# system() call in perl

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I want to make a `system()` call in a perl script and, because I want to redirect `stdin` and `stdout`, I think I need to pass a single string to `system()` and let the shell interpret the metacharacters.  However, I do not seem to be able to correctly detect when the program called via `system()` segfaults.

The perl `system()` man page at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html cautions "When system's arguments are executed indirectly by the shell, results and return codes are subject to its quirks."  Should I be concerned about this?

My code for testing the return value of `system()` is pretty much identical to the example given on the same man page (just above the warning I mention) but in retrospect that appears to be for calling `system()` with a LIST.

So, I tihnk my core issue is, how do I detect how a program terminated that was called in a shell from perl's `system()`.  Apologies if this is a repeat question but I cannot find it addressed anywhere before.  FWIW I'm running the script on a Fedora distro of linux.

Many thank.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you have a look at [IPC::Open2](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html) and [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html)

What you are trying to do is a bit too complicated for `system` which is more or less geared up to running a command, and then capturing output.

`IPC::Open2` allows you to open an exec pipe to a process, and attach your own filehandles to `STDIN` and `STDOUT`, meaning you can do bidirectional communication. (Open3 also allows `STDERR`).

Catching signals and errors on your attached process is a bit more complicated - the only thing you're *fairly* sure to get is a return code. With system, `$?` should be set automatically, but with `IPC::Open[23]` you may need to use `waitpid` to catch the return code.

Comment: They're so low level! IPC::Run3 and IPC::Run are so much easier to use.